# How can I send my Python Code (Which has pip modules) to a friend who doesn't have Python installed?

Tags: python, module, sharing, transfer

I wrote a Text Grammar Checker in Python for a friend of mine. Since he doesn't have Python installed, I searched for ways to get it to him, but there was always a catch. Compiling it to a .exe file doesn't work because it uses a module called `pyspellchecker` which uses a deprecated module called `indexer` (At least I think that's why it doesn't work). Another option would be to use an online IDE, but I could find none that could run my code using the modules it uses. Is there any good option left for me or is this a lost cause? I'd really appreciate any help

Here's the source code if required: https://gist.github.com/AaryanGamer/093385d3df463282117edf2021b7cbc2

Comment: One option is to get him to install Python, which seems like the obvious choice to me... another would be to use docker but then he'll need to install docker. Finally, you could make it a web-service, then he wouldn't need to install anything.

Comment: You can try https://repl.it/languages/python. It should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

- Docker is the 1st option : Docker installation required for your friend.
- Deploy your script as simple web service is the 2nd option : Your friend need just Browser.
- The third option that I found convenient for your use case is using **PyInstaller**, That freezes (packages) Python application into stand-alone executable app.

Documentation link https://www.pyinstaller.org/

Answer (score 0):

My first instinct would be to use a virtual environment (`venv`), and send your friend the whole folder structure. I searched for "venv portable", and the first result - https://aarongorka.com/blog/portable-virtualenv/ - may be what you're looking for if you're both in a Linux environment.